# Beginner struggling with a grid of images at tablet size in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, image-scaling

OK, so first off I'm a designer that's been pushed into development. Have had to learn most of what I know within the last week. So apologies for my lack of knowledge.

I'm sure I've done things the wrong way but as you can see from the images I've tried creating a grid of images that will soon be clickable through to different parts of the site. Only issue is when the browser is scaled down to a tablet size things go wrong.

If anyone can help I'd appreciate it!

http://i.imgur.com/1cvq0d0.png

http://i.imgur.com/5nS6wdz.png

HTML

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
  
  <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box"><img src="images/b1.jpg" alt="test" class="img-responsive" />
   <div class="carousel-caption-rob">
    <h5>Malmaison Hotel</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box"><img src="images/b2.jpg" alt="test" class="img-responsive" />
 <div class="carousel-caption-rob">
    <h5>Malmaison Hotel</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box"><img src="images/b3.jpg" alt="test" class="img-responsive" />
  <div class="carousel-caption-rob">
    <h5>Malmaison Hotel</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box"><img src="images/b4.jpg" alt="test" class="img-responsive" />
  <div class="carousel-caption-rob">
    <h5>Malmaison Hotel</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box"><img src="images/b5.jpg" alt="test" class="img-responsive" />
  <div class="carousel-caption-rob">
    <h5>Malmaison Hotel</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4 box"><img src="images/b6.jpg" alt="test" class="img-responsive" />
  <div class="carousel-caption-rob">
    <h5>Malmaison Hotel</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
 
  </div>
  </div>
  
  </div>
  </div>
```

This is all the box class you can see is

```css
.box{
padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Please define "things go wrong." We need to know what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep up trying to learn this stuff! So I did not really understand why you have the content wrapped in a "col-md-6". Other then that, the "col-sm-4" in addition to the "col-xs-4" in somewhat redundant. Bootstrap is designed to be mobile first, so calling just "col-xs-4" is like calling "col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4". Another note is "row-fluid" does not exist in Bootstrap 3.

If I were to build what you are trying to make today it would look like this:

https://gist.github.com/WilliHyde/dea9bd0e193f542a648e

Please note I just did the basic framework and did not do any of the styles for font color and such.

Good luck and keep it up! Remember, the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/) are the key!

Comment: Thanks for the help Willi, worked well! Thank you also for the tips. For the design, under the nav I wanted two 6 column boxes with the grid of images on the right and a box of text on the left. That’s why I had the col-md-6. Only thing I had to do with your work is remove the left and right padding.